# Integrate kie-tools standalone BPMN editor to my react app

Tags: bpmn, kie, dmn, kogito

I am trying to integrate the BPMN standalone editor available in the kie-tools repository into my react application.
As an initial way, tried using the `<iframe>` component in order to integrate. It seemed working well.
But i am unable to customize the download activity as i am not able to get the content by using `document.getElementById("bpmn-editor-container")`.
I have tried out in a chrome browser, disabling the security so that the cross origin issue will not come up.

Answer (score 0):

The editor itself will create an `iframe` inside the container you provide to the `open` function. [Here](https://github.com/kiegroup/kie-tools/blob/main/examples/webapp/src/Pages/StandaloneEditors/DmnStandaloneEditorPage.tsx) is an usage example of the DMN editor (BPMN should be very similar) in a React page. And [here](https://blog.kie.org/2020/10/bpmn-and-dmn-standalone-editors.html) is a blog post with a comprehensive description of the parameters you can use to interact with the editor.

Comment: My requirement was to use the tools with certain customizations. Have got it up by making changes and build/run in my environment.
Thanks for the indulgence :)